# Returning to an event listener? (Code.org - Javascript)

Tags: javascript, code.org

I am relatively new to programming and am being taught by using Code.org. I believe the code is javascript, although am not too sure. The program I have made is a simple connect the dots program which I am now trying to implement levels into. However once I am at the end of a level and all of the variables are reset and the screen is changed, i cannot click on the dots.

This is due to the fact that after this section of code runs:

```css
//Finish the level, change the level 
  if(clickedX.length >= (level*2+4) - 1 && clickedY.length >= (level*2+4) - 1){
    for(var i = 1; i < level*2+4; i++){
      deleteElement(i + "Text");
    }
    clearCanvas("mainCanvas" + level);
    level++;
    setScreen("level" + level);
    setActiveCanvas("mainCanvas" + level);
    dotsX = [];
    dotsY = [];
    levelSector = [10];
    levelDiv = 300/(level*2+4);
    clickedX = [];
    clickedY = [];
    createDotCoords();
    }
```

It does not return back to how it originally got there which is the click event listener. Here is the entire program, not very long at all. I have ran out of solutions in my own head and find I am now stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```css
var dotsX = [];
var dotsY = [];
var level = 1;
var clickedX = [];
var clickedY = [];
var levelSector = [10];
var levelDiv = (300/(level*2+4));
setActiveCanvas("mainCanvas" + level);

createDotCoords();

//Searches an array for a specific number
//Adds and subtracts 4 to allow for the entire circle to be clicked
function searchVar(variable,needle) {
    for(var i = 0; i <  variable.length; i++){
      if(variable[i] === needle){
        return true;
      }
     else{
      for(var x = 1; x < 4; x++){
        if(variable[i] + x === needle){
          return true;
        }
        if(variable[i] - x === needle){
          return true;
        }
      }
      }
  }
}

//Create Dot Coordinates and Draw
function createDotCoords(){
  levelDiv = Math.round(levelDiv);

  for(var i = 1; i < level*2+4; i++){
    appendItem(levelSector,levelDiv * i);
  
    appendItem(dotsX,randomNumber(levelSector[i - 1],levelSector[i]));
    appendItem(dotsY,randomNumber(40,410));
  
    circle(dotsX[i - 1],dotsY[i - 1],4);
    textLabel(i + "Text", i);
    setPosition(i + "Text",dotsX[i - 1],dotsY[i - 1],3,4);
  }
}


//Get mouse click location and check if the location is the same
//as the dot location. Create a line between that one and the 
//previous dot if clicked already
onEvent("mainCanvas" + level, "click", function(event){
 var clickX = event.offsetX;
 var clickY = event.offsetY;
 var booX = false;
 var booY = false;
 console.log("X " + clickX + "  Y " + clickY);
 if (searchVar(dotsX,clickX)){
      booX = true;
      console.log("x is true");

      }
 if (searchVar(dotsY,clickY)){
      booY = true;
      console.log("y is true");

      }
      
if(booY && booX){
  if(clickedY.length === 0){
     appendItem(clickedY,clickY);
     }
    if(clickedY.length >= 1){
       if(searchVar(clickedY,clickY)){
          console.log("already in Y");
       }
       else{
          appendItem(clickedY,clickY);
       }
    }
        
    if(clickedX.length === 0){
        appendItem(clickedX,clickX);
     }
    if(clickedX.length >= 1){
      if(searchVar(clickedX,clickX)){
        console.log("already in X");
         }
         else{
         appendItem(clickedX,clickX);
         }
        }
        
        
    if(clickedX.length === 1 && clickedY.length === 1){
    console.log("only one dot clicked");
    setStrokeColor("green");
    circle(dotsX[0],dotsY[0],4);
    setStrokeColor("black");
    }
    else{
    setStrokeColor("green");
    circle(dotsX[clickedX.length - 1], dotsY[clickedY.length - 1], 4);
    setStrokeColor("black");
    line(dotsX[clickedX.length - 2], dotsY[clickedY.length - 2], dotsX[clickedX.length - 1], dotsY[clickedY.length - 1]);
    }
  }
//Finish the level, change the level 
  if(clickedX.length >= (level*2+4) - 1 && clickedY.length >= (level*2+4) - 1){
    for(var i = 1; i < level*2+4; i++){
      deleteElement(i + "Text");
    }
    clearCanvas("mainCanvas" + level);
    level++;
    setScreen("level" + level);
    setActiveCanvas("mainCanvas" + level);
    dotsX = [];
    dotsY = [];
    levelSector = [10];
    levelDiv = 300/(level*2+4);
    clickedX = [];
    clickedY = [];
    createDotCoords();
    }
});
```

Also any tips on formatting/general logic/programming etiquette, things like that, would be extremely helpful as well.

Comment: I tried to run your code (you said you posted the entire program), but I didn't see anything. You mentioned that the problem occurs at the end of a level, but I wasn't able to do anything at all. I'm afraid I don't fully understand what you're trying to do. However, I suspect that you will need to understand asynchronous coding in JavaScript a little better before you will be able to solve this (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that somehow in your resetting of variables and the canvas something is getting in the way of the click listener, or what is being displayed in response.  Can you post the share link for the project here?  I can take a look at the code.  (I work in App Lab every day.  So I can help with the code, or figure out if it's an actual bug).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Good to see you here! I review first answers and your answer should be a comment - because an answer is more a solution to the problem and not you telling about your work :). You can comment under the question, check it out!